# supersized Jquery causes site to be over 100% wide

Tags: jquery, supersized

file in question; http://channel5.co.nz/testing/
excuse the long load, the jpegs havent been fully optimized yet.

I am having an issue with the way the supersized slider is adding an element to the DOM, firebug is telling me its the problematic element is the a tag that wraps the img tag inside of the ul supersized loads.

I can't seem to alter the css in a way to get this to go away.

Any insight would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing the `#supersized` css to this:

```
#supersized {
box-sizing: border-box;
-moz-box-sizing: border-box;
-ms-box-sizing: border-box;
position: absolute; 
left:0; top:0; 
margin:0px; 
overflow:hidden; 
z-index:-999; 
height:650px; 

width: 100%; }
```

(This uses the `box-model` CSS3 declaration)
The default box-model adds any padding or margin to the containers computed width; e.g. in this example you have the following rule declared:

```
ul, ol { margin: 1em 0; padding: 0 0 0 40px; }
```

Which makes the computed width 100% + 40px.

You might also have been targeting the `#supersized ul` unintentionally with this rule. 
Then you only need to add `padding: 0;` to the `#supersized` rule.

For an explanation on how the box-model works, and why it is set to `content-box` as the default, check http://www.quirksmode.org/css/box.html

Comment: Thank you very much, I see what was happening there now. Also had to add padding: 0px; to fully correct it but thank you!